# authentication key error

Tags: dual-boot

I downloaded ubuntu 14.04 lts i386 from community website I did nt get any problem while installing it but now to update or to install any other application it is asking me authentication key but I ve not given any authentication key while installing.please guide me what to do

Comment: It wants your password. Use your password that you use to login.

Answer (score 0):

Okey. First mistake, you should have given a password while installing, if you have, enter that. If you haven't then follow me.

### First enter grub boot menu

Press shift while booting to enter grub boot menu. then press e to edit the script.

### Change kernel script to enter a root bash shell

After pressing e, you need to look at the second last line where it is written `ro quiet splash $vt_handoff` and change it to `rw init=/bin/bash`

### Change your password

Okey once you've entered the bash shell (you will know that you can type commands when `root@(none):~ $` is written) type `passwd <YOUR USERNAME>` and replace YOUR USERNAME with your usename.

It will ask you to enter a new UNIX password. Enter a password of your choice and now when you login, It will ask you for your password. Enter the password you chose and log in.

### Download and Install updates and anything else you want! ;)

Now that you have your admin password, enter it when it asks you to authenticate and you can install whatever you want :)

**NOTE**

If you are not the admin of your account, then enter

> adduser (USERNAME) sudo

replace the (USERNAME) with your usename and you are an admin!

Please accept this answer if it worked for you.